# Error using node_load_multiple() API for Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, module

I am building a custom module for drupal 7 which delete all nodes of a content type. I need to load all nodes of content type. For it I have this code:

```
$type = "apunte"; 
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));
```

my problem is I have a lot of nodes of this type (almost 100000) and I always get error. If I try it with another type with only 2 or 3 nodes it works ok.

When I run my module in local (windows 8.1) I get error time exeeded (it never finish) and when I run in my server (debian 6) I get error 500. I use apache in both local and server.

How I could do it when I have too many nodes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a node_load_multiple of 100 000 nodes, you will get an array of 100 000 node object + their custom fields meaning that you will likely get millions of mysql requests and all this taking a big amount of ram.

To delete a huge amount of nodes, query your database to extract all the nids,  split you array of nids in packets of 50 or 100 nids. And loop on each packet to make your node_load_multiple (why don t you use node_delete_multiple?).

If this still take.longer than the max.excution time of your php.ini and you can not change it. You can use the batch api of drupal so each packet will be dealt as a separate http request and so the max execution time will only affect the delete of 50/100 nodes.

Edit :
Try this :

```
$sql = 'SELECT nid FROM node n WHERE n.type = :type'; 
$result = db_query($sql, array(':type' => 'apunte'))->fetchCol(); 
foreach (array_chunk($result, 100) as $chunk) {
  node_delete_multiple($chunk);
}
```

Comment: So, do you think if I use batch api I can reduce the time of delete all nodes? I had changed my code to  $sql = 'SELECT nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :type';
  $result = db_query($sql, array(':type' => 'apunte')); foreach ($result as $imp) node_delete($imp->nid); and now I don't get error, but it spend so much time to delete all nodes. How could I use batch api to reduce this time. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Try splitting your array of results from the query in packets of 100 inside your foreach with array_chunk() then use the node_delete_multiple. If this doesn't work try the batch api : http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-batch-api